# Writing regression in tensorflow but why the MSE doesn't decrease gradually?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am writing an regression gradient update process in tensorflow. Randomly initialize theta and compute gradient for update using "tf.assign". Also, i am printing out the MSE value every 100 iteration. However, I didn't see the MSE number decrease after iterations. Please let me know why it doesn't decrease gradually? Anything wrong with my following code?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

housing = fetch_california_housing()
m, n = housing.data.shape
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(housing.data)
scaled_data = scaler.transform(housing.data)
housing_data_plus_bias = np.c_[np.ones((m,1)), scaled_data]


n_epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01

# [1] Construction Phrase
x = tf.constant(housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X") 
y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1,1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")

theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n + 1, 1], -1.0, 1.0), name="theta") # initialize randomly n+1 X 1 array for thetas
y_pred = tf.matmul(x, theta, name="predicitions")

error = y_pred - y
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name="mse")

gradients = 2/m * tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), error)
update_op = tf.assign(theta, theta - learning_rate * gradients)


# [2] Execution Phrase
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(init)

   for epoch in range(n_epochs):

       if epoch % 100 == 0:
           print(mse.eval())
       sess.run(update_op)


   best_theta = theta.eval()
```

Output:

```
9.366995
9.366995
9.366995
9.366995
9.366995
9.366995
9.366995
9.366995
9.366995
9.366995
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with integer division. In Python 2, the standard division operator computes integer and not float division. In the line `gradients = 2/m * tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x), error)`, `2/m` evaluates to `0`, so you have no gradient. Add `from __future__ import division` to the top of your script and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes! That solves the issue. It makes sense that the gradient update is learnt on the decimal level. Thanks so much!